# Multiple Messages & Issues Searching Lua Tables

Tags: lua

I am attempting to make a Lua script for an online community I am a part of, I am having a problem when I attempt to search through a table array I believe. It doesn't detect the results I want.

The way it is supposed to work is that when someone types `/gps [streetname]` it will search the table at the top, detect the matching streetname & the coordinates and then set a waypoint to that relevant position.

At the moment it works when there is just one entry in the table, but when I put more, it will provide the error message for any non-matching streets & then the waypoint set message for the matching streets. I've Googled and don't appear to be able to find anything to help.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
waypoint = {
  {404.08, -920.23, 'sinnerstreet', 'Sinner Street'},
  {360.85, -956.46, 'atleestreet', 'Atlee Street'},
  {500.48, -956.80, 'littlebighornavenue', 'Little Bighorn Avenue'},
}

RegisterCommand('gps', function(source, args, rawCommand)
  for k,v in pairs(waypoint) do
    x, y, streetname, displayname = table.unpack(v)
    results = ""

    if args[1] == nil then
      if IsWaypointActive() then
        SetWaypointOff()
        TriggerEvent('chatMessage', '^1^*GPS Navigation: ^r^7Your GPS system has been reset.')
      return end
    elseif args[2] == nil and args[3] == nil then
      results = args[1]
    elseif args[2] ~= nil and args[3] == nil then
      results = args[1] .. args[2]
    else
      results = args[1] .. args[2] .. args[3]
    end

    results = string.lower(results) -- This convertes the args into lower case
  end

  -- This locates the streetname and sets a waypoint to it for the player
  if string.find(streetname, results) then
    SetNewWaypoint(x, y)
    TriggerEvent('chatMessage', '^1^*GPS Navigation: ^r^7Your waypoint to ^1' .. displayname .. '^r^7 has been set.')
  else
    TriggerEvent('chatMessage', '^1^*GPS Navigation: ^r^7There has been an error with your street name, please try again.')
  end
end)

TriggerEvent('chat:addSuggestion', '/gps', 'This creates a waypoint to your designated street. ^*USE: /gps [streetname]')
```

Comment: First of all, you don't seem to use the `rawCommand` parameter, so you might as well remove it. Lua will not complain if a function is called with more parameters than it needs, it just discards the extra ones, and it is generally considered bad style to have parameters / variables that aren't used because it just confuses people. If you want to show that the function gets a parameter it doesn't use, it is common to add a `_` before the argument name.

Comment: Same for `for` loops; if you only need the value, it is common to write `for _,v in ...`

Comment: Would you have any idea how I'd get the desired effect? I've made the changes you suggested, but I still am unable to get the command to work?

Comment: I don't even fully understand what you want, but I can tell you what your code does (see my answer) and at the very least that doesn't seem what you want it to do. The sad news is, you'll probably have to try again almost from scratch.

Comment: I basically want the table to store the coordinates for the street name, then when a player types in /GPS [streetname] it will pull the street name & co-ordinates from the table and SetNewWaypoint for them on their map.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, your code makes little to no sense, and it's probably because you're not using all the nice stuff Lua has to offer.

```
{404.08, -920.23, 'sinnerstreet', 'Sinner Street'},
```

You're storing redundant data there. The third value is really just the fourth one with spaces removed and all lowercase.

```
'sinnerstreet' == ('Sinner Street'):gsub("[^%l]", ""):lower()
```

In english: take "Sinner Street", **g**lobally (meaning in the entire string) **sub**stitute everything that is not a lowercase (`%l`) letter with nothing (`""`), then make the result of that lowercase. What you get is "sinnerstreet".

```
x, y, streetname, displayname = table.unpack(v)
```

Using globals there, that's not good. Globals are the devil. Don't use them.

Then, a few lines further down:

```
SetNewWaypoint(x, y)
```

Think about it for a moment. You set `x` and `y` in each iteration of your for loop. After the loop is done, they always contain the coordinates of the last waypoint you iterated over. I doubt that's what you want. Use `local`; it forces you to think what you want the scope of your variables to be, which will help you spot this kind of problem.

```
elseif args[2] ~= nil and args[3] == nil then
  results = args[1] .. args[2]
```

Unless you specifically want to limit it to 3 arguments, which I doubt, you can also use `table.concat` to concatenate all the values in a sequence (read: array)

```
results = string.lower( table.concat(args) )
```

The thing that puzzles me is why you do this in a loop. For every waypoint, you set `result` to the same value, which is all the arguments concatenated and converted to lower case.

now what though? You check if `result` (what the user searched for) contains `streetname`, which, as we have previously found out, contains the name of the last waypoint in the list.

## Using tables for searching

Lua has tables, one of if not the most powerful general-purpose data structure in programming.

```
local map = {}
for _,waypoint in ipairs(waypoints) do
  map[waypoint[3]:lower()] = waypoint
end
```

This will get you something that looks about like this:

```
local map = {
  sinnerstreet = {404.08, -920.23, 'sinnerstreet', 'Sinner Street'},
  atleestreet = {360.85, -956.46, 'atleestreet', 'Atlee Street'},
  littlebighornavenue ={500.48, -956.80, 'littlebighornavenue', 'Little Bighorn Avenue'},
}
```

and if you want to know if a street exists, you can just do this:

```
if map['atleestreet'] then
  print(map.atleestreet[4])
end
```

1. `if` treats everything that isn't `false` or `nil` as truthy, so you can just write `map['atleestreet'] in the condition
2. `my_table['text']` can be written as `my_table.text`
3. Looking up string indices in a table is pretty fast because of how it's implemented.

## Conclusion

Try thinking your code through. If necessary, go through it line by line, writing down what values the variables hold in each moment. If you've been at it for a while, get some rest first or do something else for a while.

Then set your variables to `local` wherever possible (read: everywhere), figure out what needs to be inside and outside the loop and try again.

## Remarks

Instead of `if something == nil` you can just write `if not something`, and `if something ~= nil` just `if something`

## Apologies

Sorry for the long wall of text and using spaces inside brackets, but I wanted things to be specially easy to understand.

Comment: I'll give this a go, this is my first time ever coding on Lua, or coding at all for that matter. This has massively confused me but I'll try and use it. Thank you,